# Can't edit textbox on the listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, textbox

I have some troubles with the textbox or my brain. I can't understand what's the reason of unedittable textbox. I mean, i have listview with 3 columns:"Name","Code","Binding".
By clicking on the "Name", the first and the second column become editable. After my edit, i push button "Save"...and nothing is happened. Can't understand such a simple thing. Why it's not working? 
Sorry for mistakes, i'm here for the 1st time

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentMain" ContentPlaceHolderID="centerContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="i_ListContainer" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <asp:ListView ID="CpzListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem"
            OnItemCreated="i_UserLV_ItemCreated" OnItemInserted="i_UserLV_ItemInserted" OnItemEditing="i_UserLV_ItemEditing"
            OnItemInserting="i_UserLV_ItemInserting" OnItemUpdated="i_UserLV_ItemUpdated"
            OnItemUpdating="i_UserLV_ItemUpdating">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mGrid">
                    <th style="width: 150px">
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 150px">
                        Code
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 50px">
                        Binding
                    </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="i_viewEditLB" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text='<%#Bind("cpzname") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="i_viewUserFioLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("code") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 80px">
                        <a href='<%# GetUrl(Eval("cpzname"), Eval("code"))%>'>Bindindg</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbCpzName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cpzname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbCpzCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("code") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSave" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the c# code, hope you'll help me.

```
    namespace WebApplication2.MemberPages
{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateBinding();
        }

        private void UpdateBinding()
        {
            DataTable dt = AOneConnectDB.ExecuteQuery("select id, cpzname, code from cpz");
            if (dt == null) return;

            CpzListView.DataSource = dt;
            CpzListView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void i_UserLV_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            CpzListView.EditIndex = -1;
            UpdateBinding();
        }

        private string GetValue(users key)
        {
            return CpzListView.Items.Count > 0 ? CpzListView.SelectedDataKey[key.ToString()].ToString() : string.Empty;
        }

        protected void i_UserLV_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            CpzListView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            CpzListView.SelectedIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            UpdateBinding();
        }

        protected void i_UserLV_ItemInserted(object sender, ListViewInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            // must empty
        }

        private string ControlValue(string controlName, ListViewItem item)
        {
            object c = item.FindControl(controlName);
            if (c is TextBox) return (c as TextBox).Text;
            if (c is CheckBox) return (c as CheckBox).Checked ? ADataBase.TRUE : ADataBase.FALSE;
            if (c is DropDownList) return (c as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
            return null;
        }

        protected void i_UserLV_ItemUpdated(object sender, ListViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            // must empty
        }

        protected void i_UserLV_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CpzListView.SelectedDataKey != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CpzListView.SelectedDataKey["id"].ToString()))
            {
                var cpzId = CpzListView.SelectedDataKey["id"];
                var cpzName = ControlValue("tbCpzName", CpzListView.EditItem);
                var cpzCode = ControlValue("tbCpzCode", CpzListView.EditItem);
                string updateCpzQuery = string.Format(@"update cpz c
                                            set c.cpzname = {0}
                                            and c.code = {1}
                                            where c.id = {2}", cpzName, cpzCode, cpzId);
                if (AOneConnectDB.ExecuteNonQuery(updateCpzQuery))
                {
                    AGUI.ShowMessage(MessageType.Success, "CPZ Modified.");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void i_UserLV_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            // must empty
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write page load method code like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
            return;
        UpdateBinding();
    }
```

In your code edited data lose befor editing code run, because when you click on save button first page load will execute and it bind your list view with old datas(UpdateBinding) then i_UserLV_ItemUpdating will execute. break point will help you undrestand how it work.

Comment: This is better way do this:
        
            if(!IsPostBack)
                UpdateBinding();

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code. you miss small thing.

To get data always actual you need to set **EnableViewState="false"**. The main thing is that setting this just for specific input is not enough. This worked for me only after I set page level view state like this.

```
 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication8._Default" 
EnableViewState="false" %>
```

Comment: thanks EnableViewState="false" actually helped to work, but not as i expected.The trouble is that i have similar page with identical page settings, and it works functionally fine, but this page is not. `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CPZ.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.MemberPages.WebForm1"
    MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="ЦПЗ" EnableEventValidation="false" %>`